# How to get a mysql datetime field as a datetime in php?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am new to PHP and MYSQL so this should be a pretty basic question.

I am querying a mysql database and getting three fields into an array. One of the fields type is datetime, but with my current query, it is being captured as a string.

This is my code:

```
$myquery = mysql_query ("SELECT id,text,when FROM messages ORDER BY cuando DESC");
 $nrows = mysql_num_rows ($myquery);
 for ($i = 0; $i < $nrows; $i++) {
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($myquery);
 $when = $row["when"];
```

I've been googling and I think i have to use the AS operator in my query, but I dont' know how. How can I do this? If possible, just by changing the query...

Thanks!

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. in PHP: `$when = strtotime($row["when"]);`
2. in mySQL: `SELECT id, text, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( when ) AS when FROM...`

Comment: The MySql solution worked. Not very sure why the first time it didnt. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a unix timestamp, you can either do it in your query or in php.

In your query:

```
$myquery = mysql_query ("SELECT id,text,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(when) FROM messages ORDER BY when DESC");
```

in PHP:

```
$when = strtotime($row['when']);
```

Edit: `WHEN` being a reserved MySQL keyword, this query will give an error. Use something else for your date field.

Comment: Thank you. But its not working. $when is NULL right now. By thew way, i am doig this on a WAMP environment, maybe UNIX_TIMESTAMP doesnt work there?

Comment: The 'when' field MUST be a date, datetime or timestamp type column... Did you check that it is? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp If not, of what type is the when column ?

Comment: 'When' is actually a reserved keyword in sql and this statement will give an error. I actually tested this query, replacing 'when' by 'cuando' and got the expected result. Editing my post to reflect that

Comment: Good point, but forget about that. In my code it is "cuando", the spanish word for "when", but I translated it here for clarity. Thanks for the effort